# Issue in creation of SQLite database in Doxygen 1.9

Tags: sqlite, doxygen

I have recently tried retrieving the output from Doxygen using SQLite output format. The documentation of Doxygen specifies that if GENERATE_SQLITE3 = YES then the output would be in sqlite.db. However when I do it, I get the following warning -
`warning:ignoring unsupported tag 'GENERATE_SQLITE3' at line 8, file Doxyfile.`
The SQLite database is thereby not created. I have SQLite installed in the system.

The version of Doxygen is 1.9 - Cloned from Git repository - https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen

The following is my Doxygen config file (Doxyfile) -

```
INPUT = //Some C Files
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
GENERATE_XML = NO
GENERATE_SQLITE3 = YES
SQLITE3_OUTPUT = sqlite
SQLITE3_RECREATE_DB = YES
XML_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
GENERATE_HTML = NO
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
```

Is there any other configuration that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the SQLITE3 features in doxygen, doxygen hast to be created in the CMake step with`-Duse_sqlite3=ON`.

In the current documentation a note was missing specifying this, a proposed pull request has been submitted in the mean time (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8412).